# Selenium | Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService | Driver info: driver.version: unknown (SessionNotCreated)' | C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, selenium-remotedriver

Try to start selenium with chrome by remoteDriver with a hub.
I create a config.json for capabilities, configuration etc...
I manage to run tests with IE and Firefox but can't with Chrome.
When start my test with chrome, I get this mistake :

```
System.InvalidOperationException : 'Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
... Driver info: driver.version: unknown (SessionNotCreated)'
```

I run my test with chrome V84 also I use chromeDriver84. I define my version like this :

```
 "browserName":"chrome",
     "browserVersion" : 84.0,
     "maxInstances":10,
     "seleniumProtocol":"WebDriver",
     "webdriver.chrome.driver": "D:/Tools/Selenium/WebDrivers/chromedriver84.exe"
```

I try  "version" : 84.0 and  "version" : "84.0" and  "version" : 84 and  "version" : "latest" etc...
But i understand why driver.version is unknown .

Thanks in advance !